# React material-ui TimePicker clock hands not lined up

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get the TimePicker to work right. For some reason the clock hands don't lineup with the numbers on the clock.

[Hour hand offset on 5 o'clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnJev.png)

[Minute hand pointing at 15 but clock reads 16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx1xC.png)

- Material-UI: 0.15.0
- React: 15.1.0
- Browser: Chrome and Safari

Here's the TestPage:

```
import React from 'react';

import TimePicker from 'material-ui/TimePicker';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

require('styles/base/pages/myPage/TestPage.scss');

const TestPage = () => (
  <div>
    <RaisedButton label="Default" primary />
    <TimePicker hintText="test" />
  </div>
);

export default TestPage;
```

Here's the index.js of the application:

```
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

injectTapEventPlugin();

render(
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
...
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

The TestPage is being rendered on one of the routes within index.js.

Let me know if you what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: are you applying custom css to the clock? just looking at the pics it looks like the hand isn't completely centered vertically which would make it look like it's pointing somewhere else. it looks 10px off or so

Comment: Thanks! Just double checked this, as it turns out bootstrap's styles were interfering with the clock hand.

Bootstrap uses the rule `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` which really messes up the way the clock is displayed. The clock hand circle and clock container (for lack of a better term) need to have the style `box-sizing: content-box;`.

Comment: Fixed in master, and will be in 0.15.1.